# I can not run the app after I update Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Ok, here is the thing:

1. I am using Xamarin.Form to build an app that targets both iOS and Android. I am using Xamarin Studio for Mac
2. I create the app and the solution creates App, App.Droid, App.iOS project.
3. In every project there is an indication that show some packages need to be updated.
4. I run the Droid project in a Samsung S5 API 21, without doing the update, and the app is installed in the device.
5. I do the update of the packages, to update Xamarin.Form in 20.0.+ version base on the feedback of this question: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57283/unable-to-find-a-version-of-xf-compatible-with so I just update the Xamarin.Form package.
6. I run again in a Samsung S5 21 but there are some errors : `/Users/crs/Projects/time.al/Droid: Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip and extract it to the /Users/crs/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v4/23.0.1.3/content directory. (XA5209) (time.al.Droid)`

What can I do, because I need to update the Xamarin.Forms to the latest version, but I am stuck with this for a long time.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests? Last time I saw this error, doing what the error message says solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You should:
1-Download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip
2-Go to: /Users/crs/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v4/23.0.1.3/content
3-Copy the repository downloaded here and unzipped

This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You should:

1. Download https://dlssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip
2. Then go [username]\AppData(hidder folder)\Local\Xamarin\zip

and delete any zip file from there. then rebuild you project and goto step 2 location  you should found there something like 96659D653BDE??????????.zip file which visual studio try to download stop build and copy step 1. downloaded file in step 2 location and rename that file with this 96659D653BDE?????????? and remove 96659D653BDE??????????.zip file which is uncompleted.

3. Then go to visual studio and rebuild your project wait and Viola you got rebuild success. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the corrupted file (android_m2repository_r22.zip) and try again. This happend me like two times by the bad internet connection.